# How to get Class with type param

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to get Class>.

In order to mock a Observer i need it's class.
I have tried using `Observer<Int>::class.java` but get "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal"

MWE (lines 1-2 are the important ones, domain logic and mockito verification included for completeness):

```
val clazz = Observer<Int>::class.java  // Error
val observer: Observer<Int> = mock(clazz)

addObserver(observer)
val y = 1
setObservedValue(y)


verify(observer).onChanged(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just a single `Observer::class`, it doesn't depend on the type parameter. So you can write

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val clazz = Observer::class.java as Class<Observer<Int>>
```

Or if you run into this more than once (which is likely)

```
inline fun <reified T> mock(): T = mock(T::class.java)
```

called as

```
val observer = mock<Observer<Int>>()
```